# Large jasper report to Excel causes a corrupt file

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, corrupt

I'm using jasperreports 3.5.3 for generating a large (but simple) report. Only a table with strings.

When I list a big enough selection the generated file is corrupt. Excel alerts the user and some data is corrupted. But if I filter the data to show some rows including the offending one it's generated normally.

Does someone have experience with this corrupt excel file results?

**Tip:** it happens in a Linux/Apache+JBoss server, but the same code on a local Windows/Jboss works fine. I don't think the Apache in the middle has something to do. It must be something in the generation itself.

Comment: This was a bug fixed in 3.6.0: http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports/tracker/view.php?id=4014

Answer (score 2):

It seems that jasperreports 3.5.3 can use two kinds of "excel writers". The by default exporter is `JRXlsExporter` and doesn't work very well with big files (at least in my Spring MVC project).

A workaround is using the other exporter, based in JExcelAPI. I could export the data without trouble with this one.

For making **jasperreport use JExcelAPI into a Spring MVC instalation** you have to write a personalized class. Its very simple:

```
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporter;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JExcelApiExporter;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.AbstractJasperReportsSingleFormatView;

// this is the view class you'll use, instead of JasperReportsXlsView
public class JasperReportsJExcelApiView extends AbstractJasperReportsSingleFormatView
{
    // copied from JasperReportsXlsView
    public JasperReportsJExcelApiView()
    {
        setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    }

    protected JRExporter createExporter()
    {
        // we create the JExcelAPIExporter, not the JRXlsExporter
        return new JExcelApiExporter();
    }

    // copied from JasperReportsXlsView (I think it says: write binary data, not text)
    protected boolean useWriter()
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You'll need the jxl.jar in your classpath from the JExcelAPI 2.6 distribution.